# customize std::shared_ptr deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

In *C++ Primer 5th*, I've seen something like this:

> `shared_ptr<T> p(p2,d)` p is a copy of the `shared_ptr p2` except that p uses that p uses the callable object d in place of `delete`

But when I test it:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class DebugDelete {
public:
    DebugDelete(std::ostream &o = std::cerr) : os(o) {}
    template <typename T> void operator()(T *p) const
    {
        os << "delete unique_ptr" << std::endl;
        delete p;
    }
private:
    std::ostream &os;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> sptr, sptr1(sptr, DebugDelete());
}
```

what I quote seems wrong, `sptr1(sptr, DebugDelete())` doesn't work, but  `sptr1(new int(42), DebugDelete())` works well.

So is it allowed to use a `shared_ptr` and a deleter to construct a `share_ptr` like in *C++ Primer 5th*? 
Thanks.

Comment: If there were a constructor taking a `shared_ptr` and a custom deleter, you could then have two different `shared_ptr`s sharing ownership of the same object but with two different deleters.  Which should be used when the object is destroyed?

Comment: @aschepler good explanation for why can't construct a `shared_ptr` like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`shared_ptr` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

For the case where it does compile :

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sptr, sptr1(new int(42), DebugDelete());
```

It uses the fourth constructor noted:

> `template< class Y, class Deleter > shared_ptr( Y* ptr, Deleter d );`
>     (4)

For the other case you mention :

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sptr, sptr1(sptr, DebugDelete());
```

It can't use this constructor because you're not passing a pointer, you're passing a different `shared_ptr` object.

Going down the list further, none of the constructors match the arguments here and thus you end up with a compilation error. That code is not standard-conformant which leads me to believe it's a tadbit different than what's in the book.